# Как достать подвыражение REGEXP_SUBSTR в MariaDB?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, mariadb

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(name_eng, 'cost\_([a-z]+)\_production') AS reg FROM `cost_districts_name`
```

Необходимо вытащить подвыражение в круглых скобках.
**MariaDB 10.1**

Comment: Какие сложности у вас возникли? Группа имеет номер 1, извлеките ее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто взять [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regexp_replace/):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name_eng, 'cost_([a-z]+)_production', '\\1') AS reg 
  FROM `cost_districts_name`
```

А т.к. под капотом там должен быть PCRE, то можно и заморочиться с просмотром вперёд/назад

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(name_eng, '(?<=cost_)([a-z]+)(?=_production)') AS reg 
  FROM `cost_districts_name`
```

ЗЫ: подчёркивание в регулярках обычно эскейпить ни к чему...